# Include googletest into CMake installation process

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a C++ project that I am able to compile into a static library using CMake. I am also testing this project using googletest but after sifting through previous answers on getting the utility working with CMake projects I am stuck.

The root dir of my project contains the necessary code to compile my project into a static lib in the standard paths. Here is an example of the CMakeLists.txt file in my tests/ directory :

```
# Download and install GoogleTest
include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(
  googletest
  URL https://github.com/google/googletest/archive/03597a01ee50ed33e9dfd640b249b4be3799d395.zip
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(googletest)

# TESTS
add_executable(
    bin test.cpp

)

# enable testing
enable_testing()

target_link_libraries(
    bin 
    lib 
    # GTest::gtest 
    GTest::gtest_main 
    pthread

)

include(GoogleTest)
gtest_discover_tests(bin)
```

This successfully build the googletest library and my tests but doesn't run them automatically. I had to run `ctest` manually after my process to see the result of my tests. I want my typical `cmake.. , make, make install` process to build my project upon successful tests. Is there a way to do this? I think it makes sense for tests to pass as the first step before installing the library itself. Is there also a way to check for an installation of googletest on the system before installing the package from source?

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding - both `gtest_discover_tests()` and `gtest_add_tests()` are only for replacing CMake's `add_test()` i.e. they discover and add tests to the `ctest` executable .

It is also not standard that you run tests during `cmake <...>, make <...>, make install`. So a good thing to think about is, to make an option that allows the end-user to decide if he/she wants to run tests.

That being said the easiest way on how to get your tests to run let's say - **post build**. Is to [add_custom_command()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html), e.g.:

```
if(RUN_MTPK_TESTS)
  add_custom_command(TARGET test_openMTPK
               POST_BUILD
               COMMAND ctest --output-on-failure)
endif()
```

Then by running: `cmake -S[source] -B[build] -DRUN_MTPK_TESTS=TRUE` you will, after running `make`, execute your tests through `ctest`.

To answer your last question, is there a way on how to check if `googletest` is already installed? **Yes** there is and it requires some additional conditions in your `CMakeLists.txt`. Example:

```
find_package(GTest)
if(NOT GTest_FOUND)
  #FetchContent, etc...
endif()
#rest of your cmakelists
```

EDIT: Check [find_package()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html) for more information regarding the use of `find_package` and what variables it sets and how can you customize the behavior of said command.